# Comment dit-on « work shift » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

J'aimerais savoir s'il y a un équivalent pour le « work shift » en français.

Je ne peux que penser à « horaire de travail », mais je ne suis pas sûre.

Comment: Pouvez-vous svp. donner un contexte ou expliquer si le _work shift_ a un sens particulier pour vous ? Merci.

Comment: Pourquoi douter de la traduction habituelle « horaires de travail » qui correspond pourtant bien à l'usage habituel de *work shift* en anglais ?

Comment: Parfois, on parle de tranche horaire aussi. Pour le travail organisé en trois-huits, dit travail posté.

Answer (score 3):

We may say `horaires de travail`, but also `heures de travail`, `quart de travail`.

According to the manager, there is at least one bilingual employee on each **shift**.

Selon le gestionnaire, il y a au moins un employé bilingue à chaque **quart de travail**.

---

`créneau` can also be used depending on context. We usually use the word créneau for time slot, but can also be used for shift.

E.g.:

We have three shifts.

Nous avons trois créneaux.

---

Other interesting info. from [here](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/shift):

équipe du matin = morning shift

équipe de jour = day shift

équipe de nuit = night shift

Comment: I would have translate "we have three shift" as "nous avons trois  équipes" , "créneau" is mostly a critical time period (when certain transaction/maintenance must be completed).

Answer (score 0):

Effectivement, *Work shift* peut être traduit en "horaires de travail", mais aussi en "espace de travail", dans ce cas, son équivalent anglais serait plus "Workspace".

S'il vous faut des exemples, dites-le moi.

Answer (score 0):

N.B. is mostly right, but I guess it depends on where you are. In French Canada, the usual translation for "work shift" is "quart de travail". "Créneau" is not used at all for this.

Comment: J'aurais plutôt tendance à utiliser le terme "pause de travail", en Belgique